# Can't Find google-play-services_lib

Tags: android, mobile, admob

I'm trying to include Google Mobile Ads into my app (AdMob) so i followed the Google documentation

> https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/?hl=en

but I am stuck at the first step "Add and reference the Google Play services library project"

I can't find the **google-play-services_lib**, in the properties of my project even when I installed the "Google Play Services"
thank you